# How do I use contour plot to plot a constant (not value of z at a specific height) within a for loop to loop across domain?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

[image]

I break up my big domain into smaller domains and within the small domains (rectangles), a conserved quantity is constant. I am tasked with having to plot that quantity over the entire domain. I heard contour plot works for this but I keep on getting a null blank result. The purpose of the for loop is to advance through the domain and plotting the quantity in the next domain.

I am basically trying to fill each rectangle in the link with a specific value.

Assume `se` is an array containing constants.
Thanks!

```
n2=0
count=1
for i=1:ny-1;
    for j=1:nx-1;
        x1=X(i,j);
        y1=Y(i,j);
        x2=X(i,j+1);
        y2=Y(i,j+1);
        x3=X(i+1,j+1);
        y3=Y(i+1,j+1);
        x4=X(i+1,j);
        y4=Y(i+1,j);

        nl=[n2*nx+j,n2*nx+j+1,n2*nx+j+nx,n2*nx+j+1+nx];

        xcd=(x1+x2+x3+x4)/4;
        ycd=(y1+y2+y3+y4)/4

        [mx,my]=meshgrid(x1:x2,y1:y3)

        sp=se(count)*ones(size(mx))

        plot([x1,x2,x3,x4],[y1,y2,y3,y4],'k')
        hold on
        contourf(mx,my,sp)
        colormap default
        colorbar
        hold on

        axis([0,55,-25,25])
        count=count+1
    end
    n2=n2+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the overwhelming response..use patch() instead of countour.